# Authorize(Roles="Admin") does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm writing ASP.NET application with Identity as authorization engine. I wrote my custom user and role stores and they seem to work correctly. However, for some unknown reason, attempt to use `Authorize` with role on controller's action fails and redirects to `Home/Index`. The action looks like following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Manage()
{
    return View();
}
```

The redirection is being done silently, so I cannot hook debugger anywhere (especially that action filtering is being done before running action).

I guess this may not be enough to diagnose the problem, so just tell me in comments, what additional information do you need and I'll edit the question.

Why doesn't it work?

---

**Edit**: Configuration in Startup.cs

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();

        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });            
    }
```

---

**Edit:** Another action:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        // This returns FALSE
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ok");

        var userManager = UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>();
        // This returns TRUE
        if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), "Admin"))
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ok");

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: First, remove the attribute and verify you go to Manage corrctly. A failure to authorize should have sent you to Login, not Home/Index

Comment: Is this an OWIN-enabled application? If so, can you show your authorization configuration?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, it works correctly if I replace `[Authorize]` with `[AllowAnonymous]`

Comment: @TiesonT. I'm pretty new to OWIN, is the `Configuration` method in `Startup.cs` the method you are refering to?

Comment: @Spook If you're following the common template, yes (which looks to be the case with your edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

1. What is the login page set to? I'm guessing you are either unauthenticated or unauthorized, and MVC is sending you to the login page (which is probably set or defaulted to "/"
2. If you are sure you are logged in (authenticated), double check that your user does indeed have the admin role (is authorized).
3. I believe the user store has a method you can override to see what's returned for the user's roles. It's probably worth setting a breakpoint there and see what's going on.

Comment: Regarding 3., I set a breakpoint both in `GetUserRoles` and in `IsUserInRole` and neither is being run

Comment: Then I would bet you are not actually logged in. Create another controller method which returns a new (call it "UserInfo" or something and check the info of your user, something like
@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? "Logged in" : "Not logged in") (or just check in the debugger).

How are you logging on?

Comment: I guess you were on the right track. I *was* logged in, but this was via cookie - I logged in before adding role to user. When I logged out and then logged in, immediately `GetRolesForUser` was called and now all `[Authorize]` with roles work.

Comment: Does it mean, that roles are being checked only during logging in? And [Authorize] filter does not check **current** user roles?

Comment: Yes - the roles will be stored (encrypted) in the cookie/token, so you will have to re-login after changing roles.